# Parameters in POST call to Data Service in Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I'm migrating some data services from DSS to EI but I have problems with the parameters in POST calls. I published a Data Service with a query exposed as a REST resource using the methods POST and GET, just for testing. Then I try to call it using cURL. 
The GET is easy because I only need to append the parameter to the URL, but for the POST I try passing it using -d and a JSON or XML structure but always the server responds with error 400 (bad request). 
If the resource have no parameters both calls works fine.

Can anyone tell me the right way to pass the parameters to the RESTFUL resource when I use the POST method?

Answer (score 0):

If you publish this service as wsdl service do you have same problems with methods, thats analogies to your post methods? I was catch similar problem when don't set request_box parameter of my service to on. It was look as I send request without parameters, but they was send correcltly in fact.

Comment: No. If I use the WSDL to make a call via SOAP all works fine.